# Jira REST API/JQL to determine tickets that were pulled into open sprint

Tags: rest, api, jira, jira-rest-api, jql

I am able to get all the issues from the api using `https://{jira_instance}/rest/api/2/search?jql=Sprint={sprintID}`, however the individual issues do not have this information.

Using Jira's REST API, or the JQL query language (which I can push into the api), I'd like to be able to determine which issues in an open sprint were pulled in after the sprint was started, as opposed to those brought in at the sprint inception.

In the old grasshopper api type calls (which has very disjointed documentation across the web), there was a "reports" type endpoint which may have been useful, but that doesn't seem to be present in the `../rest/api/2..` api.

Any and all suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the [ScriptRunner add-on](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview) with JIRA Server, you can use one of their [custom JQL functions](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/jql-functions.html#_addedaftersprintstart) and embed the following JQL into your query:

```
issueFunction in addedAfterSprintStart("Sample Scrum Board", "Sample Sprint 3")
```

Comment: Thanks - I don't have administration access so will have to find out what plugins are installed tomorrow but it is at least a possibility! Thank you.

Comment: If you drop the above into a standard JQL search field in the regular JIRA UI and it works (at least after adjusting for your board/sprint names), you know you have ScriptRunner installed. :-)

Comment: Haha - well yes! 

Comment: We do \0/ :D

Thank you - I have not marked this as accepted (yet) because it uses a 3rd party, however if there are no other answers then I will mark this as correct. Thank you!